# Cross-Compiling openCV for ARM on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have been trying to compile openCV for arm on my ubunto machine. 
When i compile to arm i am getting the below linkage errors:
uiEscoreDrv.o: In function `main':
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to`cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x33c): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to`cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x390): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to`cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to `cv::destroyWindow(std::string const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.o: In function`displayCoreOutput(escore_output&)':
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1304): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1358): undefined reference to`cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_, int, double, cv::Scalar_, int, int, bool)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x13ac): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1452): undefined reference to`cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_, int, double, cv::Scalar_, int, int, bool)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1482): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1492): undefined reference to`cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::*InputArray const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.o: In function `displayAnalytics(escore_output&)':
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1b44): undefined reference to`cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Point*, cv::Point_, cv::Scalar_ const&, int, int, int)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1be0): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1cb6): undefined reference to`cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_, cv::Point_, cv::Scalar_ const&, int, int, int)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1e58): undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1e88): undefined reference to`cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
uiEscoreDrv.cpp:(.text+0x1e98): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

When i compile to regular linux, i dont get this the problem.

I have done all the steps from:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html

I have added the below to my Makefile:
LDFLAGS += -L./ -L/usr/local/lib -lutils `pkg-config  --cflags --libs --static opencv`

After the compilation i have done the below steps:
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo cp -rf /home/user/eyeSight_projects/opencv-3.2.0/platforms/linux/build_hardfp/install/lib/* .

But i am still getting this error...

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Thanks,
Oren

Answer (score 0):

It was a compilation issue :-)
I didnt add the -I to the compilation line:

LOCAL_INCLUDE_FLAGS= -I/usr/local/include -I ../../api/ -I ../../
 $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++  -std=c++11 -lsdtc++ -fPIC -c -o uiEscoreDrv.o -fPIC $(CFLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDE_FLAGS) uiEscoreDrv.cpp